# Values of Spacetime Dimension and Virasoro Generator Ambiguity in Bosonic String Theory

Tags: string-theory

I have already asked a similar question but I was suggested to split the questions so I do that now.

In the book by Green, Schwarz and Witten spurious states are introduced to find values for the Spacetime Dimension and the Virasoro Generator Ambiguity such that there are no negative norm states in the physical spectrum. These spurious states obey
$$
 (L_0 -a)\phi=0
$$
and
$$
 (\phi,\psi)=0 \quad \forall \text{ physical states }\psi
$$
Then clearly a physical spurious state has zero norm since it is orthogonal to itself.
So they proceed by finding an explicit form of some spurious states and imply the physical state condition $L_{m>0} ~ \psi=0$ on them to find 
$$
a=1 \quad \text{and} \quad D=26
$$
So my question is:
Since $a$ and $D$ are constant on the whole Hilbert Space and we just calculated it for a subspace, namely the physical spurious states, does that not mean that $a=1$ and $D=26$ have to take these values on the whole Hilbert Space? If so then why is $a\leq1$ and $D\leq26$ still possible?

The argument can also be read in a paper by Kevin Wray ([here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~kwray/papers/string_theory.pdf)) on pages 64-70

Comment: By now I habe read a dozen of different sources that all follow this reasoning but then state a<1 and D<26 are still possible. I am kind of desperate right now 'cause I really don't get it.

Comment: Search on the web with keywords "non-critical bosonic string theory", for instance [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-critical_string_theory#The_critical_dimension_and_central_charge). The price to pay to have other dimensions than $26$ is to get a dilaton field which is  not constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This shows that one can formulate String Theory in less than $26$ Dimensions, but I still don't understand why the argument above is wrong, i.e. that if a Theory has at least one physical spurious state then $D=26$ follows for the whole Hilbert Space.

Comment: I think that the constants $a$ and $D$ are parameters of your model, so IMHO, they are the same for the whole Hilbert space. After, it is up to you to describe what are the physical states in your model.

Comment: Ahhh okay. So in non-critical Bosonic String Theories there can't be any physical spurious states but in critical Theories there must be at least one?

Comment: I did not say that. I don't know if there are physical spurious states in non-critical bosonic string theories, but probably the identification of  the spurious and physical states is different (you would have consider the dilation field, etc..)

Comment: What do you mean by Identification? The definition of physical states is not arbitrary is it? The subsidiary condition is closely related to the classical one and spurious states are just defined like that. And I think the ground state with appropriate momentum is, with this definition, always spurious and physical.